# How to add image parameter in Gloudemans Shoppingcart

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I am trying to add an image parameter in Gloudemans Shoppingcart but am getting an error

`Please supply a valid weight`

I am pretty sure this is because am inserting the image parameter in a position configured for "weight", now my question is where do I add the image parameter? it doesn't seem to exist in any of the Gloudemans config files, please assist, below am listing all files under config in Gloudemans shoppingcart

**Cart Controller**

```
public function addItem($id)
    {
        $product=Product::find($id);
        Cart::add($id,$product->product_name,1,$product->price,$product->product_image);
        
        return back();
    }
```

**Cart.php file under folders vender\bumbummen99\src**

```
<?php

namespace Gloudemans\Shoppingcart;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Contracts\Buyable;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Contracts\InstanceIdentifier;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\CartAlreadyStoredException;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\InvalidRowIDException;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\UnknownModelException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Session\SessionManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Cart
{
    const DEFAULT_INSTANCE = 'default';

    /**
     * Instance of the session manager.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * Instance of the event dispatcher.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher
     */
    private $events;

    /**
     * Holds the current cart instance.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $instance;

    /**
     * Holds the creation date of the cart.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * Holds the update date of the cart.
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * Defines the discount percentage.
     *
     * @var float
     */
    private $discount = 0;

    /**
     * Defines the tax rate.
     *
     * @var float
     */
    private $taxRate = 0;

    /**
     * Cart constructor.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Session\SessionManager      $session
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events
     */
    public function __construct(SessionManager $session, Dispatcher $events)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->events = $events;
        $this->taxRate = config('cart.tax');

        $this->instance(self::DEFAULT_INSTANCE);
    }

    /**
     * Set the current cart instance.
     *
     * @param string|null $instance
     *
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart
     */
    public function instance($instance = null)
    {
        $instance = $instance ?: self::DEFAULT_INSTANCE;

        if ($instance instanceof InstanceIdentifier) {
            $this->discount = $instance->getInstanceGlobalDiscount();
            $instance = $instance->getInstanceIdentifier();
        }

        $this->instance = sprintf('%s.%s', 'cart', $instance);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current cart instance.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function currentInstance()
    {
        return str_replace('cart.', '', $this->instance);
    }

    /**
     * Add an item to the cart.
     *
     * @param mixed     $id
     * @param mixed     $name
     * @param int|float $qty
     * @param float     $price
     * @param float     $weight
     * @param array     $options
     *
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    public function add($id, $name = null, $qty = null, $price = null, $weight = 0, array $options = [])
    {
        if ($this->isMulti($id)) {
            return array_map(function ($item) {
                return $this->add($item);
            }, $id);
        }

        $cartItem = $this->createCartItem($id, $name, $qty, $price, $weight, $options);

        return $this->addCartItem($cartItem);
    }

    /**
     * Add an item to the cart.
     *
     * @param \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem $item          Item to add to the Cart
     * @param bool                              $keepDiscount  Keep the discount rate of the Item
     * @param bool                              $keepTax       Keep the Tax rate of the Item
     * @param bool                              $dispatchEvent
     *
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem The CartItem
     */
    public function addCartItem($item, $keepDiscount = false, $keepTax = false, $dispatchEvent = true)
    {
        if (!$keepDiscount) {
            $item->setDiscountRate($this->discount);
        }

        if (!$keepTax) {
            $item->setTaxRate($this->taxRate);
        }

        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($content->has($item->rowId)) {
            $item->qty += $content->get($item->rowId)->qty;
        }

        $content->put($item->rowId, $item);

        if ($dispatchEvent) {
            $this->events->dispatch('cart.added', $item);
        }

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);

        return $item;
    }

    /**
     * Update the cart item with the given rowId.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     * @param mixed  $qty
     *
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    public function update($rowId, $qty)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        if ($qty instanceof Buyable) {
            $cartItem->updateFromBuyable($qty);
        } elseif (is_array($qty)) {
            $cartItem->updateFromArray($qty);
        } else {
            $cartItem->qty = $qty;
        }

        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($rowId !== $cartItem->rowId) {
            $itemOldIndex = $content->keys()->search($rowId);

            $content->pull($rowId);

            if ($content->has($cartItem->rowId)) {
                $existingCartItem = $this->get($cartItem->rowId);
                $cartItem->setQuantity($existingCartItem->qty + $cartItem->qty);
            }
        }

        if ($cartItem->qty <= 0) {
            $this->remove($cartItem->rowId);

            return;
        } else {
            if (isset($itemOldIndex)) {
                $content = $content->slice(0, $itemOldIndex)
                    ->merge([$cartItem->rowId => $cartItem])
                    ->merge($content->slice($itemOldIndex));
            } else {
                $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);
            }
        }

        $this->events->dispatch('cart.updated', $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);

        return $cartItem;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the cart item with the given rowId from the cart.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove($rowId)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->pull($cartItem->rowId);

        $this->events->dispatch('cart.removed', $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Get a cart item from the cart by its rowId.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     *
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    public function get($rowId)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        if (!$content->has($rowId)) {
            throw new InvalidRowIDException("The cart does not contain rowId {$rowId}.");
        }

        return $content->get($rowId);
    }

    /**
     * Destroy the current cart instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function destroy()
    {
        $this->session->remove($this->instance);
    }

    /**
     * Get the content of the cart.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function content()
    {
        if (is_null($this->session->get($this->instance))) {
            return new Collection([]);
        }

        return $this->session->get($this->instance);
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of items in the cart.
     *
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->sum('qty');
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of items instances in the cart.
     *
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function countInstances()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->count();
    }

    /**
     * Get the total price of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function totalFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($total, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $total + $cartItem->total;
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the total price of the items in the cart as formatted string.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function total($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->totalFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the total tax of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function taxFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($tax, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $tax + $cartItem->taxTotal;
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the total tax of the items in the cart as formatted string.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function tax($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->taxFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the subtotal (total - tax) of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function subtotalFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($subTotal, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $subTotal + $cartItem->subtotal;
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the subtotal (total - tax) of the items in the cart as formatted string.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function subtotal($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->subtotalFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the discount of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function discountFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($discount, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $discount + $cartItem->discountTotal;
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the discount of the items in the cart as formatted string.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function discount($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->discountFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the price of the items in the cart (not rounded).
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function initialFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($initial, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $initial + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->price);
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the price of the items in the cart as formatted string.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function initial($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->initialFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the price of the items in the cart (previously rounded).
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function priceTotalFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($initial, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $initial + $cartItem->priceTotal;
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the price of the items in the cart as formatted string.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function priceTotal($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->priceTotalFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the total weight of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function weightFloat()
    {
        return $this->getContent()->reduce(function ($total, CartItem $cartItem) {
            return $total + ($cartItem->qty * $cartItem->weight);
        }, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the total weight of the items in the cart.
     *
     * @param int    $decimals
     * @param string $decimalPoint
     * @param string $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function weight($decimals = null, $decimalPoint = null, $thousandSeperator = null)
    {
        return $this->numberFormat($this->weightFloat(), $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Search the cart content for a cart item matching the given search closure.
     *
     * @param \Closure $search
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function search(Closure $search)
    {
        return $this->getContent()->filter($search);
    }

    /**
     * Associate the cart item with the given rowId with the given model.
     *
     * @param string $rowId
     * @param mixed  $model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function associate($rowId, $model)
    {
        if (is_string($model) && !class_exists($model)) {
            throw new UnknownModelException("The supplied model {$model} does not exist.");
        }

        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $cartItem->associate($model);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Set the tax rate for the cart item with the given rowId.
     *
     * @param string    $rowId
     * @param int|float $taxRate
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTax($rowId, $taxRate)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $cartItem->setTaxRate($taxRate);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Set the global tax rate for the cart.
     * This will set the tax rate for all items.
     *
     * @param float $discount
     */
    public function setGlobalTax($taxRate)
    {
        $this->taxRate = $taxRate;

        $content = $this->getContent();
        if ($content && $content->count()) {
            $content->each(function ($item, $key) {
                $item->setTaxRate($this->taxRate);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the discount rate for the cart item with the given rowId.
     *
     * @param string    $rowId
     * @param int|float $taxRate
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDiscount($rowId, $discount)
    {
        $cartItem = $this->get($rowId);

        $cartItem->setDiscountRate($discount);

        $content = $this->getContent();

        $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);
    }

    /**
     * Set the global discount percentage for the cart.
     * This will set the discount for all cart items.
     *
     * @param float $discount
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setGlobalDiscount($discount)
    {
        $this->discount = $discount;

        $content = $this->getContent();
        if ($content && $content->count()) {
            $content->each(function ($item, $key) {
                $item->setDiscountRate($this->discount);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store an the current instance of the cart.
     *
     * @param mixed $identifier
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function store($identifier)
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();

        if ($identifier instanceof InstanceIdentifier) {
            $identifier = $identifier->getInstanceIdentifier();
        }

        if ($this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
            throw new CartAlreadyStoredException("A cart with identifier {$identifier} was already stored.");
        }

        $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->insert([
            'identifier' => $identifier,
            'instance'   => $this->currentInstance(),
            'content'    => serialize($content),
            'created_at' => $this->createdAt ?: Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);

        $this->events->dispatch('cart.stored');
    }

    /**
     * Restore the cart with the given identifier.
     *
     * @param mixed $identifier
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function restore($identifier)
    {
        if ($identifier instanceof InstanceIdentifier) {
            $identifier = $identifier->getInstanceIdentifier();
        }

        if (!$this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
            return;
        }

        $stored = $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())
            ->where('identifier', $identifier)->first();

        $storedContent = unserialize(data_get($stored, 'content'));

        $currentInstance = $this->currentInstance();

        $this->instance(data_get($stored, 'instance'));

        $content = $this->getContent();

        foreach ($storedContent as $cartItem) {
            $content->put($cartItem->rowId, $cartItem);
        }

        $this->events->dispatch('cart.restored');

        $this->session->put($this->instance, $content);

        $this->instance($currentInstance);

        $this->createdAt = Carbon::parse(data_get($stored, 'created_at'));
        $this->updatedAt = Carbon::parse(data_get($stored, 'updated_at'));

        $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->where('identifier', $identifier)->delete();
    }

    /**
     * Erase the cart with the given identifier.
     *
     * @param mixed $identifier
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function erase($identifier)
    {
        if ($identifier instanceof InstanceIdentifier) {
            $identifier = $identifier->getInstanceIdentifier();
        }

        if (!$this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->where('identifier', $identifier)->delete();

        $this->events->dispatch('cart.erased');
    }

    /**
     * Merges the contents of another cart into this cart.
     *
     * @param mixed $identifier   Identifier of the Cart to merge with.
     * @param bool  $keepDiscount Keep the discount of the CartItems.
     * @param bool  $keepTax      Keep the tax of the CartItems.
     * @param bool  $dispatchAdd  Flag to dispatch the add events.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function merge($identifier, $keepDiscount = false, $keepTax = false, $dispatchAdd = true)
    {
        if (!$this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
            return false;
        }

        $stored = $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())
            ->where('identifier', $identifier)->first();

        $storedContent = unserialize($stored->content);

        foreach ($storedContent as $cartItem) {
            $this->addCartItem($cartItem, $keepDiscount, $keepTax, $dispatchAdd);
        }

        $this->events->dispatch('cart.merged');

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Magic method to make accessing the total, tax and subtotal properties possible.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function __get($attribute)
    {
        switch ($attribute) {
            case 'total':
                return $this->total();
            case 'tax':
                return $this->tax();
            case 'subtotal':
                return $this->subtotal();
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the carts content, if there is no cart content set yet, return a new empty Collection.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    protected function getContent()
    {
        if ($this->session->has($this->instance)) {
            return $this->session->get($this->instance);
        }

        return new Collection();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new CartItem from the supplied attributes.
     *
     * @param mixed     $id
     * @param mixed     $name
     * @param int|float $qty
     * @param float     $price
     * @param float     $weight
     * @param array     $options
     *
     * @return \Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem
     */
    private function createCartItem($id, $name, $qty, $price, $weight, array $options)
    {
        if ($id instanceof Buyable) {
            $cartItem = CartItem::fromBuyable($id, $qty ?: []);
            $cartItem->setQuantity($name ?: 1);
            $cartItem->associate($id);
        } elseif (is_array($id)) {
            $cartItem = CartItem::fromArray($id);
            $cartItem->setQuantity($id['qty']);
        } else {
            $cartItem = CartItem::fromAttributes($id, $name, $price, $weight, $options);
            $cartItem->setQuantity($qty);
        }

        return $cartItem;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the item is a multidimensional array or an array of Buyables.
     *
     * @param mixed $item
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isMulti($item)
    {
        if (!is_array($item)) {
            return false;
        }

        return is_array(head($item)) || head($item) instanceof Buyable;
    }

    /**
     * @param $identifier
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->where('identifier', $identifier)->exists();
    }

    /**
     * Get the database connection.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    private function getConnection()
    {
        return app(DatabaseManager::class)->connection($this->getConnectionName());
    }

    /**
     * Get the database table name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getTableName()
    {
        return config('cart.database.table', 'shoppingcart');
    }

    /**
     * Get the database connection name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getConnectionName()
    {
        $connection = config('cart.database.connection');

        return is_null($connection) ? config('database.default') : $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Formatted number.
     *
     * @param $value
     * @param $decimals
     * @param $decimalPoint
     * @param $thousandSeperator
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function numberFormat($value, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator)
    {
        if (is_null($decimals)) {
            $decimals = config('cart.format.decimals', 2);
        }

        if (is_null($decimalPoint)) {
            $decimalPoint = config('cart.format.decimal_point', '.');
        }

        if (is_null($thousandSeperator)) {
            $thousandSeperator = config('cart.format.thousand_separator', ',');
        }

        return number_format($value, $decimals, $decimalPoint, $thousandSeperator);
    }

    /**
     * Get the creation date of the cart (db context).
     *
     * @return \Carbon\Carbon|null
     */
    public function createdAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get the lats update date of the cart (db context).
     *
     * @return \Carbon\Carbon|null
     */
    public function updatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
}
```

I have tried checcking out Crinsane's repo but there is no documentation about this

Comment: check this pull commit https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/pull/502/commits/7a5b842d9b4507a3755654a74df0d334d79371ab

Comment: I guess you also need to pass weight as shown in the commit

Comment: I have tried the suggestion in the commit, it seems to work but I think it stores blanks `public function addItem($id)
    {
        $product=Product::find($id);
        Cart::add(['id'=>$id,'name'=>$product->product_name,'qty'=>1,'price'=>$product->price,'weight' => 0,'options' => ['image' => $product->product_image]]);
        
        return back();
    }` when trying to access the image in my view it shows blank, I have tried `dd($cartItems)` and shows blank under options ` +options: Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions {#1281 ▼
        #items: []
      }`

Comment: "I'm afraid you're using the 'store' method in another way than it's designed for. The idea is that you can 'store' the cart for a later point in time, and 'restore' it when the user wants it again.

It's not really designed to store the cart in the database 'realtime' so to say." This is what is told by Crinsane here , https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart/issues/397

Comment: @Anil I am aware that the package is not used to store persistent data like a database, I know that the Cart data gets destroyed when a session expires. And am okay with that configuration.. If I am storing the items incorrectly then why am I able to access other parameters in my view and return the correct values except the image parameter?

Comment: correct values except the image parameter?what do you mean by that, you need to have php-imagick extension to show images in image intervention class does that solve the issue

Comment: @Anil thanks for the help, I managed to install php_imagick extension as well as the image intervention package in my Laravel project. I can now access the image directly from the cart in the view